# Meteor: measure and minimize initial page download size (and time)

Tags: performance, meteor

i have a meteor project (web not app) and when i view the site on my iphone over wifi it works great, but when i view the site over LTE i see a white page or sometimes a black page.  this implies to me that the site is taking too long to download too much so the browser is giving up.  (maybe i'm in left field)

so, i was wondering if anyone knows how to measure how large the initial meteor download will be for the first page.  and some tips to minimize that size.

for example, i know there are some stock images that i can remove from my code but what i'd like to see is how much of an impact that is making (if any), and to look for additional optimizations to shrink that initial download size.

also, if there are other gotchas to be aware of in this case, i'd love to hear those as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome open your site then open the inspector and go to the *Network* tab and hit shift-cmd-R. This will completely reload the page and measure the network traffic. At the bottom of the chart you'll get a summary of network requests and bytes transferred such as:

```
33 requests | 31.4KB tranferred | etc...
```

Comment: that helps.  thanks.  looks like you also have to look at the websockets tab and include the downloads there.  that was insightful to see how much data was coming down there.

Comment: this helped me prove that those stock images weren't included at all, so that wasn't going to help with performance.

Comment: I forgot to mention you might need to hard reload, the images could be cached.